# How do we break the loop without adding the sentinel to the average?

Tags: c++, loops, breakpoints, sentinel

As the code stands now, the sentinel is being included in the calculation for the average. Any pointers on how to break the loop without including the sentinel?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{

int fahr=0,cent=0,count=0,fav=0;

while (fahr!=-9999)
{
    count ++;       
    cout<<"Input the fahrenheit temp to be converted to centigrade or enter -9999 "<<endl;
    cin>>fahr;
    cent=(float)(5./9.)*(fahr-32);
    cout<<"The inputed fahr "<<fahr<<endl;  
    cout<<"The cent equivalent "<<cent<<endl;



}
fav=(float)(fav+fahr)/count;
    cout<<"Average"<<fav<<endl;
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your code isn't calculating an average.  You'd need some accumulator like `total += fahr` each loop.  Then your average should be `total / count`.  Also, there's no need to cast the total to `float` if the result is stored as an `int`.  You'll end up with the same result as integer division anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Make the code run in an infinite loop, and use break to terminate the loop if you see -9999.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{

int fahr=0,cent=0,count=0,fav=0;

while (true)
{
    count ++;       
    cout<<"Input the fahrenheit temp to be converted to centigrade or enter -9999 "<<endl;
    cin>>fahr;

    if (fahr == -9999)
       break;

    cent=(float)(5./9.)*(fahr-32);
    cout<<"The inputed fahr "<<fahr<<endl;  
    cout<<"The cent equivalent "<<cent<<endl;
}

fav=(float)(fav+fahr)/count;
cout<<"Average"<<fav<<endl;
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add one more line after

```
cout<<"The cent equivalent "<<cent<<endl;
```

add:

```
fav += cent;
```

and change

```
fav=(float)(fav+fahr)/count;
```

to:

```
fav=(float)fav/count;
```